# NHL Rule Question

Tags: rules, ice-hockey

In a recent Bruins/Blackhawk game a Bruins goal was waived off because a Bruins Player knocked the puck down with his hand. If you watch the replay carefully you can see the puck was going to go wide until the goalie played the puck with his stick and knocked it into his own goal. Was that the right call or should it have been a goal since the goalie actually put it in the goal?

Comment: Hi @BrentWhitney, welcome to Sports.SE - could you kindly [edit](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/24646/edit) your question title to something more specific? This will help any other people with the same / similar question to yours find this one and, hopefully, a useful answer - "NHL Rule Question" is a bit ambiguous :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a specific rule for exactly this  situation. It was the correct decision The goal should be, and was, disallowed.

> 67.6 **Disallowed Goal** - A goal cannot be scored by an attacking player who bats or directs the puck with his hand into the net. A goal cannot be scored by an attacking player who bats or directs the puck and it is deflected into the net off any player, goalkeeper or official. When the puck enters the net on a clear deflection off a glove, the goal shall be allowed.